# PayPal Sandbox to Live Transaction Search API not working?

Tags: r, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

NB: I believe the problem I am experiencing has to do with a general PayPal API issue, but I'll include my R code anyway:

I have written some code in R using the PayPal Transaction Search API. It simply grabs transactions and displays them in a dataframe (table).

This is working fine with my Sandbox credentials (it displays the one transaction I have there). However, when I change to live credentials, there is no data coming back, even though there are far more transactions in the associated live account.

To "go live" my code changes the request URL to "https://api.paypal.com" and the username and password to the live credentials. It doesn't do anything else.

I am wondering if I need to take some other steps? I have already made sure the relevant boxes are ticked under the Live App settings (so Transaction API is ticked for the live app). I am also assuming that the developer account/live app is associated with the PayPal account email it lists, so will draw transactions from that (real) account.

```
library(curl)
library(lubridate)
library(rjson)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html
# https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/transaction-search/
# https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/#


sandbox.creds <- list(username = "sandbox_username",
                password = "sandbox_password")

live.creds <- list(username = "live_username",
                      password = "live_password")

# instantiate vars
api_url <- " "
user_pwd <- " "

access.token <<- NA
access.token.expires <<- NA


live.or.sandbox <- function(live) {
  
  # set these vars to NA whenever this function is called
  # otherwise the live vs. sandbox API will not find the access token
  
  access.token <<- NA
  access.token.expires <<- NA
  
  if (live == TRUE) {
    print("setting to live credentials")
    api_url <<- "https://api.paypal.com"
    user_pwd <<- paste0(live.creds[[1]],":",live.creds[[2]])
  }
  else {
    print("setting to sandbox credentials")
    api_url <<- "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com"
    user_pwd <<- paste0(sandbox.creds[[1]],":",sandbox.creds[[2]])
  }
  
}

# set live or sandbox

live.or.sandbox(live = TRUE)


# body --------------------------------------------------------------------



get.access.token <- function() {
  
      req_access_token <- curl::new_handle() %>%
        handle_setopt(copypostfields = "grant_type=client_credentials", userpwd = user_pwd, verbose=TRUE, httpauth = 1L) %>%
        handle_setheaders("Accept" = "application/json", 
                          "Accept-Language" = "en_US") %>%
        curl_fetch_memory(url = paste0(api_url, "/v1/oauth2/token")) %$% content %>% 
        rawToChar %>% rjson::fromJSON()
      
      access.token.expires <<- lubridate::as_datetime(lubridate::as_datetime(Sys.time()) + lubridate::dseconds(req_access_token$expires_in))
      access.token <<- req_access_token$access_token
  
}

get.access.token.if.current.not.expired <- function() {
  
  current_time <- lubridate::as_datetime(Sys.time()) 
  
  cat("access token state: ", access.token)
  # only request a new access token if one hasn't been generated yet and if previous requests haven't expired
  if (is.na(access.token)) {
    print("no access token")
    get.access.token()
  }
  
  else {
    print("already access token")
    
    if(access.token.expires < as_date(Sys.time())) {
      print("last access token has expired")
      print("get new access token")
      get.access.token()
    }
    
    else {
      print("use old access token")
      cat("time left is ", 
          as.integer(difftime(access.token.expires,
                   as_datetime(Sys.time()),
                   units = "secs")))
    }
    
  }
    
}



make.transaction.request <- function(start_date, end_date) {
  
  # check if new access token required
  get.access.token.if.current.not.expired()
  
  bearer.access.token <- paste0("Bearer ", access.token)
  req_transactions <- new_handle() %>%
    handle_setheaders("Accept" = "application/json", 
                      "Authorization" = bearer.access.token) %>%
    curl_fetch_memory(url = paste0(api_url,"/v1/reporting/transactions?fields=all&start_date=",start_date,"&end_date=", end_date, "&fields=all")) %$% content %>% 
    rawToChar %>% rjson::fromJSON()
  
  print("transaction request")
  print(req_transactions)
  
  # just return transaction details
  req_transactions$transaction_details
}

format.date.rfc339 <- function(date) {

  format(lubridate::as_datetime(date), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
  
} 


# current date in required rfc 339 format
# the maximum date range is 30, so several requests must be made to go beyond this

return.transactions <- function(number_months, tidy_transactions, live) {
  
  if(live == TRUE) {
    live.or.sandbox(live = TRUE)
  }
  
  else {
    live.or.sandbox(live = FALSE)
  }
  
# a month here really means 30 days. 
# thus this function returns number_months * 30 days backwards from the present
  
  current_date <- lubridate::as_datetime(Sys.time())

  # convert dates to rfc339 format
  dates <- lapply(1:number_months, function(x) format.date.rfc339(current_date - ddays((x*30))) )
  
  # get a transaction request for each date range
  res <- list()
  
  for (i in 1:number_months) {
    
    if (i < number_months) {
      start_date <- dates[[i+1]]
      end_date <- dates[[i]]
      res[[i]] <- make.transaction.request(start_date, end_date)
    }
  }
  
  if (tidy_transactions == TRUE) {
   
    transactions <- bind_cols(res)
  
    names(transactions) <- c("transaction_id", "transaction_event_code",
                              "date", "transaction_updated_date",
                              "currency_code", "value", "transaction_status",
                              "transaction_subject", "currency_code", "value",
                              "currency_code", "value2", "protection_eligibility")
  
  
     transactions <- transactions[, c("transaction_id", "date", "value")]
  
     transactions <- transactions %>% mutate(value = sapply(value, function(x) paste0("£", x)),
                                             date = sapply(date, function(x) format(as_date(x), format="%B %d %Y"))
     )
  }
  
  else {
    res
  }

}


transactions_live <- return.transactions(4, tidy_transactions = FALSE, live = TRUE)

# empty
transactions_sandbox <- return.transactions(4, tidy_transactions = FALSE, live = FALSE)
```

Here is the response I get in live mode:

```
* Connection 90 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 90
*   Trying 66.211.168.123...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.paypal.com (66.211.168.123) port 443 (#91)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.paypal.com
*  start date: Jul 28 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  2 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.paypal.com" matched cert's "api.paypal.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'my_username'
> POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.paypal.com
Authorization: Basic blahblahQVZtUWtXlcasdklsdS3VTME93sadjksdjpYlRSXzE2Si11LTVBS19DYnFVX1BlWlBQREcwT25OeTVSTHdQOTVyV0F4WUasdjasdoOUM4bzluQmN6MGg5ckFzbWQ=
User-Agent: RStudio Desktop (1.2.5033); R (3.6.3 x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 x86_64 darwin15.6.0)
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en_US
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 972
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 13:05:54 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 431a3fb2c4f43
< X-Paypal-Token-Service: IAAS
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< 
* Connection #91 to host api.paypal.com left intact
```

Except for the "Strict-Transport-Security" header, this seems the same as in sandbox mode:

```
* Connection 91 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 91
* Connection 92 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 92
*   Trying 173.0.82.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.sandbox.paypal.com (173.0.82.78) port 443 (#93)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
*  start date: Jul 27 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.sandbox.paypal.com" matched cert's "api.sandbox.paypal.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'sandbox_username'
> POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Authorization: Basic blahblahT1I3MmJrSk5asjdkasjdkasjdksajkdjaskjdksajdkjsakdadkpasdUDF6cDBscjlnTWxaMXBScnl2WmR2YU91cGM=
User-Agent: RStudio Desktop (1.2.5033); R (3.6.3 x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 x86_64 darwin15.6.0)
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en_US
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Length: 972
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 15:07:46 GMT
< Paypal-Debug-Id: 89a06d70502df
< X-Paypal-Token-Service: IAAS
< 
* Connection #93 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
```

Transaction call:

```
* Found bundle for host api.paypal.com: 0x7f835d4f5810 [can pipeline]
* Could pipeline, but not asked to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#3) with host api.paypal.com
* Connected to api.paypal.com (66.211.168.123) port 443 (#3)
> GET /v1/reporting/transactions?fields=all&start_date=2020-06-28T19:49:23Z&end_date=2020-07-28T19:49:23Z&fields=all HTTP/1.1
Host: api.paypal.com
User-Agent: RStudio Desktop (1.2.5033); R (3.6.3 x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 x86_64 darwin15.6.0)
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer blahsduas9fuyiwjwf_vX1d_p8n3keJy8ZSvyjZasdkfdkdsfdsLL8MgQf3RN0R9sEHAXystT7EXqlgasdjasdasosCsxjtBotQ

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 442
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 19:49:25 GMT
< Application_id: APP-09E52asjdasd0071E
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Caller_acct_num: YXGDSFU9DSFBU7TUE
< Paypal-Debug-Id: aadd1bcasduasd239
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< 
* Connection #3 to host api.paypal.com left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

When you request an access token, it needs to return the scope  `https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read`. If it doesn't include that scope yet, wait up to 9 hours after you added the Transaction Search permission to you REST app.

If you don't want to wait 9 hours, create a new REST app and check the box for Transaction Search before you request your first access token, which will be cached for 9 hours.

Comment: Thank you. It does return this scope, but there is still no transaction information coming through.

Comment: Well I can't tell if your own code is still caching an old one or not, but what we would need to see to help further is a log of your full transaction search request URL and the response JSON, including any headers in the response.  You can just re-run the request from curl with -v

Comment: Edited original post.

Comment: Those seem to be the oauth token request calls, which are fine at this point -- but what's not workign for you is the actual transaction search request. So your transaction search request URL, and calling that in live with curl -v (and your access token in an -H header of course) is what will be useful.

Comment: Okay, added (I think). Can't see an error, although there is a Paypal debug ID.

Comment: Well this is going to seem trivial, but the issue would appear to be your date range, `start_date=2020-06-28T19:49:23Z&end_date=2020-07-28T19:49:23Z`. Try something more recent.

Comment: Ah - yes you got it, thanks! Because Paypal limits the range you can request in one go to 31 days, my script makes n (in this case, 3) separate requests for each 30 days backwards; but a bug meant that it didn't request it for the most recent month. Thanks again Preston!